# Buscar en un dentro de un objeto de arreglos en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

Por favor tengo un objeto de arreglos y necesito buscar dentro de él para obtener los valores que corresponde para realizar un cálculo.

```
user input = "MON32";

     var opt = {
            cat1: [
                ["MON32", 23, 12, 0.5, 5, 39.87],
                ["MON41", 18, 12, 0.5, 5, 73.11]
            ],
            cat2: [
                ["PAR", 28, 12, 0.5, 15, 0],
                ["FIL", 24, 1, 0.5, 15, 0],
                ["REJ", 27, 9, 0.8, 15, 0],
                ["RET", 29, 14, 0.7, 15, 0] 
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Para contestar a esta pregunta, habría que saber si el tamaño de la matriz es siempre la misma o variable, y si el nombre de las propiedades pueden variar, si solo quieres buscar en una de las propiedades, o en todas, que salida esperas...

De todas maneras, es probable que requiera hacer una búsqueda recursiva.

¿Que intentaste? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de que salida esperas?

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios y disculpa por no dar mas detalles pero son nuevo en esto y estoy atascado. El tamaño de la matriz si es siempre la misma pero las propiedades del objeto si van a ir aumentando. No he intentado nada.  Lo que necesito obtener es son los valores numéricos de la matriz una vez que el usuario escoja su opción. En el ejemplo si escogió  "MON32" necesito los datos 23, 12, 0.5, 5, 39.87

Comment: Entonces las propiedades podrían ser cat1, cat2, cat3...etc hasta un número indefinido? Y la búsqueda debe ser en todos ellos?
¿Ese objeto lo creas tu o te viene dado? Si lo creas tu te aconsejo usar una única matriz de 3 dimensiones, en vez de ir generando propiedades nuevas, eso facilitaría el código.

Comment: Que mala decisión de estructura de datos, pero en fin, al final si que se podrá. Por allí te sugiero que leas un poco sobre el bucle [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in) para recorrer los elementos de un objeto y luego sobre el bucle [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of) para recorrer los elementos de un `Array`. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya existe una respuesta, pero de todas maneras pongo la mía:

```
let palabraBuscar = "MON32";

for(const property in opt){
    var arraysInternos = opt[property];
    for(const element of arraysInternos){
        if(element[0] == palabraBuscar)
            console.log(element.slice(1));
    }
}
```

Inicialmente tienes un objeto, por el cual debes usar `for...in`. Te aconsejo leer la documentación sobre cómo funciona [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Al utilizar dicha declaración puedes acceder a cada una de las propiedades de tu objeto, en tu caso:

```
for(const property in opt) // property tomará los valores de cat1, cat2
```

Debido a eso, puedes acceder, en la siguiente línea, al array interno que tiene cada propiedad. Aquí:

```
var arraysInternos = opt[property]; // Retornará los arrays internos
// cat1 => retornará 2 arrays
// cat2 => retornará 4 arrays
```

Dado que ahora tienes arrays, puedes utilizar [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
for(var element of arraysInternos) // element tomará ["MON32",...,39.87],["MON41", ...], etc.
```

Finalmente, dado que `element` es un array unidimensional, simplemente accedes al primer elemento para comparar con la palabra que buscas.

Si la encuentra, retornas el resto del array con [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), dicho método toma una porción de tu array dependiendo del índice de inicio o fin que le pongas. En este caso:

```
element.slice(1); //Retorna el array desde el índice 1 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                  //                                    x,[o, o, o, o, o]
```

`slice()` recibe dos parámetros, inicio y fin, pero cuando no le indicas el parámetro de fin, por defecto toma el tamaño del array, es decir, hasta el final del array.

```js
var opt = {
            cat1: [
                ["MON32", 23, 12, 0.5, 5, 39.87],
                ["MON41", 18, 12, 0.5, 5, 73.11]
            ],
            cat2: [
                ["PAR", 28, 12, 0.5, 15, 0],
                ["FIL", 24, 1, 0.5, 15, 0],
                ["REJ", 27, 9, 0.8, 15, 0],
                ["RET", 29, 14, 0.7, 15, 0] 
            ]
        }
        
let palabraBuscar = "MON32";

for(const property in opt){
    var arraysInternos = opt[property];
    for(const element of arraysInternos){
        if(element[0] == palabraBuscar )
            console.log(element.slice(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let userInput = "MON32";

let opt = {
    cat1: [
        ["MON32", 23, 12, 0.5, 5, 39.87],
        ["MON41", 18, 12, 0.5, 5, 73.11],
    ],
    cat2: [
        ["PAR", 28, 12, 0.5, 15, 0],
        ["FIL", 24, 1, 0.5, 15, 0],
        ["REJ", 27, 9, 0.8, 15, 0],
        ["RET", 29, 14, 0.7, 15, 0],
    ],
};

let resultado = []
Object.keys(opt).forEach(key => {
    const exists = opt[key].filter(arr => arr[0] === userInput)[0];
    if(exists){
        resultado = exists.slice(1)
    }
})

console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: @awamas funciona perfecto !!